# "By cancellation" in group theory?

Tags: group-theory

I don't quite understand what the following "by cancellation" means in group theory:

http://www.calpoly.edu/~brichert/teaching/oldclass/w2003412/solutions/solutions10.pdf, p. 9.

> Thus we may suppose that $G$ contains at least three elements, which we call $e$, $a$, and $b$. We can choose $a$ and $b$ in $G$ such that $ab≠ba $ because $G$ is nonabelian. Of course, $ab, ba \in G$, and **by cancellation**, $ab≠a≠ba$ and $ab≠b≠ba$.

So how does the "by cancellation" part really work out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what that means is if $ab=a$, we can left multiply by $a^{-1}$ and get $b=e$ which is a contradiction. We can do the same thing for $ba=a$. The property in itself is called cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

The cancellation property of groups is that if $ab=ac$ for any group elements $a,b,c$, then $b=c$, i.e., we can cancel the left-most term $a$ that appears in both sides of the equation. The proof is that every group element has an inverse, and so we can multiply both sides on the left by $a^{-1}$, and then using the associativity law, we get: $ab=ac$ $\implies$ $a^{-1} (ab) = a^{-1} (ac)$ $\implies$ $(a^{-1}a)b = (a^{-1}a)c$ $\implies$ $eb=ec$ $\implies$ $b=c$.  Similarly, if $ba=ca$, then we can multiply both sides on the right by $a^{-1}$ to get $b=c$.  In effect, we can cancel the same group element from both sides of the equation (if this group element appears as the left-most term on both sides or as the right-most term on both sides).